# Changing controls in a thread safe manner

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am trying to use threadsafe calls to UI controls from a C# form.  For some reason the **BackgroundWorkerHelper** is not available, might be because of the version of C# or becuase I am deploying to a "Window CE 5.0 Device".

I have this

```
    //For ThreadSafe called to edit components
    private delegate void SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue);
    public static void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(SetControlPropertyThreadSafe), new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
        }
        else
        {
            control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
        }

    }
```

And am calling the Thread like this

```
private Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.remoteRequestBackgroundTask));

workerThread.Start();
```

Then inside the remoteRequestBackgroundTask() function I change controls like this

```
        //enable the cancel button
        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(btnCancel, "Enabled", true);
```

The problem is that when it runs, debugging stops here

```
control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
```

and I get "NotSupportedException"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [MSDN Documentation for .InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember.aspx), under **Exceptions**.  Next to `NotSupportedException`, you'll see:

> The .NET Compact Framework does not currently support this method.

In that `else` block, I believe you could do something like this instead.  This is shortened from some very similar .NET Compact Framework code I have:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
propertyInfo.SetValue(control, propertyValue, null);
```